# How to render multiple component which parent are wrapped into another multiple element in react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am creating a Project where I have multiple component in `/`. So I wrapped them into a Route with Fragment. Now from those `child` component one is `parent` of another some component.

How can I set them to Route?

##### Infomation

1. `Browser Router` are in it's parent component.
2. I can see all 4 `Dashboard, Hero, List, Footer` in Homepage.
3. I am getting nothing after `List`
4. The router will be like `/li/:liId/:olId` means `/li/1/1`. I can view only `/`

##### Code

```
<Routes>
     <Route path='/' element={
        <>
          <Dashboard />
          <Hero />
          <List>
             <Route path="/li" element={<Hi />}>
                <Route path="/:liId" element={<Hi />} >
                    <Route path="/:olId" element={<Hi />} />
                    <Route path="/i" element={<Info />} />
                    <Route path='/d' element={<Details />} />
                 </Route>
              </Route>
              <Route path='*' element={<Error />} />
           </List>
           <Footer />
        </>
       }>
      </Route>
 </Routes>
```

##### Solved with

```js
<Routes>
  <Route
    path='/*'
    element={(
      <>
        <Dashboard />
        <Hero />
        <List>
          <Outlet />
        </List>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )}
  >
    <Route path="/li/:liId" element={<Hi />}>
      <Route path="/li/:liId/:olId" element={<Hi />}/>
        <Route path="/li/:liId/i" element={<Info />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route` components that are rendering nested routes should specify the trailing `"/*"` wildcard character to allow sub-route path matching.

`Route` components should also only have either the `Routes` or another `Route` component as parent.

You can either wrap the nested routes in a `Routes` component:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path='/*'
    element={(
      <>
        <Dashboard />
        <Hero />
        <List>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="li" element={<Hi />}>
              <Route path=":liId" element={<Hi />}>
                <Route path=":olId" element={<Hi />} />
                <Route path="i" element={<Info />} />
                <Route path="d" element={<Details />} />
              </Route>
            </Route>
            <Route path='*' element={<Error />} />
          </Routes>
        </List>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )}
  />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit how-to-render-multiple-component-which-parent-are-wrapped-into-another-multiple v1]

Or render an `Outlet` for the nested `Route` components to be rendered into.

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path='/'
    element={(
      <>
        <Dashboard />
        <Hero />
        <List>
          <Outlet /> // <-- nested `Route`s render out here
        </List>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )}
  >
    <Route path="li" element={<Hi />}>
      <Route path=":liId" element={<Hi />}>
        <Route path=":olId" element={<Hi />} />
        <Route path="i" element={<Info />} />
        <Route path="d" element={<Details />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<Error />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit how-to-render-multiple-component-which-parent-are-wrapped-into-another-multiple v2]

Comment: I'm looking for you. Thankfully you answered my question. First of all I try with different style with your 1st method. It doesn't work but 2nd one is working. Thanks.
Will you please review this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082165/how-to-prevent-duplicate-modal-popup-not-scrolling-to-last-element-in-reactjs)

Comment: @mrhrifat Looks like that other question is resolved. I didn't test either implementation, but it sounds like the second version worked for you?

Comment: Yes. I can't get any component rendered with 1st suggestion. Although I test many times with changes. But then I follow 2nd one & it's work.  But I need to create path in details. Like `I have edit & added to my question with Solved With` Section. Please do check.

Comment: @mrhrifat I see. Both solutions appear to work, though I did have a typo in the first example, the `Error` route needed to be move up into the `Routes` component to fix an issue with that implementation. I also tweaked the paths. I updated my answer and added running codesandbox demos for each.

Comment: Thank you so much. After finishing all components I will try with your solved implementation. For now please will you review this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71100333/how-to-get-value-of-a-component-to-another-component)

Comment: this router v6 is so shitty.. it brings nothing usefull, it complicates routing. In v5 you could use components as a children of route, eg creating auth wrapper, now you need to go through hoops to achive this. Code becomes ugly

Comment: @PawełAndruszków That is personal opinion. In my opinion RRDv6 is vastly superior to RRDv5. It does so many things so much better than v5 that I don't miss any of the functionality that was removed. React is moving in a certain direction and if you read the `RRDv6` FAQ you'll see that RRD is traveling in the same direction. If you want a good comparison of route protection between v5 and v6 see my answer [here](/a/66289280/8690857), it's not *that drastically* different. If anything I'm assuming it's the `Outlet` component that is confusing you. I also didn't like it so much at first.