# How to prevent duplicate Modal Popup & not scrolling to last element in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I'm creating a Project where I fetch data from server & render `10` data in `10` different Bootstrap card using `map()`. Each card have a button to popup a Modal. Beside I set a `Link` to button that will show me route of that data.

#### Information

- Using `react-bootstrap` for modal with `hooks`
- Using `react-router-dom` for show `route`
- Using `useState` hooks to set data from fetched data to modal.
- All of code are in one component.
- `info_prop` & `info` are different but it works with same data.
- I have `import` all needed things & don't have any `warning or error`
- About Data Handling

  - First I get data with `useGetDataQuery()` using `chapterId`.
  - Map data & destructure  `info` data & set to state with `setInfo`
  - Send to Modal props with `info`
  - Handle of sending to `setInfo` with `handleModal`. I also try without this function. That time I do it on `onClick`.

##### Problem

- Route Problem with map()

  - I use a `Button` to show `Modal` & Wrapped the button with `Link`. Every `Link` has a uniqe ID like `1:1, 1:2, 1:3...1:10`. If I click on `1:1` button it show me the content of `1:1`. But when I close the modal the route auto change `1:1` to `1:3...1:10`.
  - I can realize that there it's render a duplicate `Modal` behind main `Modal`. I can see only 3-4 lines of back modal.
- Modal Problem

  - When I show 1-5 data with map & click button of popup modal, modal show normally with blur background.
  - When I dhow 1-10 data with map & click button of popup modal, background become pure black.(I think it's not normal)

##### Dependencies

- react-bootstrap v5
- bootstrap v5
- react-router-dom v6

##### Code

- Code of component. `Modal` in same component but in another function.

```js
function TafsirModal(props) {
    return (
        <Modal
            {...props}
            size="md"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered
        >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                    Heading
                </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <div>
                    {props.info}
                </div>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}

const InfoCom = () => {
    const { chapterId } = useParams()

    let [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
    let [info, setInfo] = useState('')
    const { data } = useGetDataQuery(chapterId)


    const handleModal = (info_prop) => {
        setInfo(info_prop)
        setModalShow(true)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        {data.map(res => (
                            <Link to={`/li/${chapterId}/${res.res_key}`} key={res.res_key} >
                                <div key={res.id} className='card my-2'>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                                            <Button onClick={() => handleModal(res.info[0].text)}>
                                                Get Info
                                            </Button>

                                            <TafsirModal
                                                show={modalShow}
                                                onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                                                info={info}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default InfoCom
```

Comment: Can you create a code-sandbox link? I am guessing it can be a rendering issue or it can also be issue where multiple modals rendering on top of each other, hence click event getting propagated. I can find out once you give a reproducible link.

Comment: Thanks but it would be a hard to create a code-sandbox because the project is very big & if I start to do it. I need to create minimum 10 files & a lot of dependencies because they are related to each one.
Beside I do check with console log that is I'm getting 10 data when I click only one button. But thankfully it's not. I'm getting only one & desired data at each button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue looks like it's the way you're handling showing your modal with
`show={modalShow}`
Whenever you click on a button to show your modal all of them are showing because they all have show modal true from modalShow. instead of using showModal state try this:

```
let [activeModal, setActiveModal] = useState('');

function handleModal(info_prop) {
  setInfo(info_prop)
  // if you have an id or something use that instead of text in set activeModal
  setActiveModal(info_prop)
}
// in map
<Button onClick=(() => handleModal(res.info[0].text)></Button>

<TafsirModal
  show={activeModal === res.info[0].text ? true : false}
  onHide=(setActiveModal(''))
/>
```

Another solution that I more commonly use is to render the modal outside of the map towards the top level of the the component and this way you could use the same logic you currently have and this way we are rendering only one modal which would be better in my opinion and easier to read.
We can do this my simply moving `<TafsirModal />` up a few levels in the tree

```
<>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        {data.map(res => (
                            <Link to={`/li/${chapterId}/${res.res_key}`} key={res.res_key} >
                                <div key={res.id} className='card my-2'>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                                            <Button onClick={() => handleModal(res.info[0].text)}>
                                                Get Info
                                            </Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
               {activeModal && <TafsirModal
                  show={modalShow}
                  onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                  info={info}
                 />
                }
            </div>
        </>
```

Comment: Edited to add a different solution that I think is better

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying your solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your first  suggestion is working. I am sending `key` to setActiveModal() instead of text. But  need some changes to it.

Comment: Do you have any idea that, If I want to change my route when I click on the Modal Show Button with the `key` of Modal text. Like if general route is `/app/1`, Then how can I change the route to `/app/1/details` on Button Click. I tried by wrapped the  button div with `Routes, Route`. It don't show the button. 
<br> I am using 1st code style.