# How to get value of a component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am creating a Project where I need to get value of a component state value to another component.

How can I get the value?

#### Information

1. Both are functional component.
2. I need to send data from A (state) to B(state).
3. A state data are set from `react dropdown` menu.Which is a button.
4. I don't use `Link or Route` to `A` dropdown that's why I can't get it with `useParams()`
5. I need to set value in `B` component which will fetch data with passing language.
6. I have import all needed things & don't have any warnings & error.

#### Code of component A

1. Send value from this `language` state to `B`

```js
const A = () => {
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState('en');
    
    return (
        <Navbar expand="xl" bg='light' expand={false}>
            <Container>
                <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title={<MdOutlineLanguage />}>
                    <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => setLanguage('en')}>English</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => setLanguage('ar')}>العربية</Dropdown.Item>
                    <Dropdown.Item as="button" onClick={() => setLanguage('bn')}>বাংলা</Dropdown.Item>
                </DropdownButton>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
};

export default A
```

##### Code of Component B

1. I need to get here `A` state value & set it to `B` state. Then pass to `useGetDataQuery` & fetch data.

```js
const B = () => {
    let [language, setLanguage] = useState('en')
    const { data } = useGetDataQuery({language })
    
    return (
        <>
            
        </>
    )
}
export default B
```

##### Redux Section

I'm using `readux & @reduxjs/toolkit` to store fetch data. Can I store my `language` data to here. Than how can get to from anywhere of my component.

1. `react-rotuer-dom` v6

```js
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [dataOne.reducerPath]: dataOne.reducer,
        [data2.reducerPath]: dataTwo.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: false
        }).concat([dataOne.middleware, dataTwo.middleware]),

})
```

Comment: I think David's answer is appropriate here - `useContext` may be better-suited. Oringal-comment: Please try to move the state up & use props + call-backs to the child-components. Suppose both A and B components are rendered using some parent component/s and those at some point up/higher in the hierarchy will be rendered by a common parent. So, keep this particular info/variable/state at that level. Then, pass it down. Or, please consider using a framework such as redux or one of the many others to help with state-management.

Comment: The two answers to everything in react: 1. Don't mutate state. 2. List state up (to a common ancestor). Number 2 is the answer to your problem here. `I need to send data from A (state) to B(state).` This tells you that the state needs to be lifted up to a common ancestor component. If you are already using redux, then these values you are sharing probably belong in your store.

Comment: @Adam @jsNoob Thanks for your information. I solve my problem by using `redux` instead of `useState()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using `useState`, you can use a global state by using [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) because I think your `language` will be use on several places as request body and of course to edit the state value, you can combine it with [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

// `UPDATE`

> working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-monad-21wnc

`MyContext`

```
import { useReducer, useContext, createContext } from "react";

const initialValue = {
  language: "id"
  // other: "value",
};

const AppContext = createContext(initialValue);

const AppReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_LANGUAGE":
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const MyContext = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialValue);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);
export default MyContext;
```

this is the `context` and `reducer` component later on use in `App.js`

`App.js`

```
import A from "./A";
import B from "./B";
import MyContext from "./MyContext";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MyContext>
      <div className="App">
        <A />
        <B />
      </div>
    </MyContext>
  );
}
```

`A.js`

```
import { useAppContext } from "./MyContext";

const A = () => {
  const [globalState, dispatch] = useAppContext();

  const onChange = (e) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CHANGE_LANGUAGE",
      payload: {
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>Start Of Component A </p>
      <input value={globalState.language} name="language" onChange={onChange} />
      <p>End Of Component A </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default A;
```

`B.js`

```
import { useAppContext } from "./MyContext";

const B = () => {
  const [globalState, dispatch] = useAppContext();

  return (
    <>
      <p>Start Of Component B </p>
      <h2>Language Val : {globalState.language}</h2>
      <p>End Of Component B </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default B;
```

Comment: I have edited my code. please see the `Redux Section`. Now how can I do it?

Comment: I never use Redux before, but i will give you `useContext` and `useReducer` example. gimme some minutes

Comment: Thanks for giving me idea to work with redux. Although I'm already using redux in my project but I'm not sure that it will be working. After your suggestion to work with `redux` instead of `useState`. then I solve my problem by following `react-redux` docs. I don't follow of your example because there I've to import 2 components in one components. But that does't suitable for my project.
But thank you so much for creating a nice example for me.